# unable to get docker to run?

Tags: 20.04, docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I was following the directions at https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-docker-on-ubuntu-20-04 and got to `sudo apt install docker-ce` seemingly without issue. Here's the output I got from that command:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  containerd.io docker-ce-cli docker-ce-rootless-extras docker-scan-plugin pigz slirp4netns
Suggested packages:
  aufs-tools cgroupfs-mount | cgroup-lite
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  containerd.io docker-ce docker-ce-cli docker-ce-rootless-extras docker-scan-plugin pigz slirp4netns
0 upgraded, 7 newly installed, 0 to remove and 91 not upgraded.
Need to get 108 MB of archives.
After this operation, 466 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu focal/stable amd64 containerd.io amd64 1.4.6-1 [28.3 MB]
Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 pigz amd64 2.4-1 [57.4 kB]
Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 slirp4netns amd64 0.4.3-1 [74.3 kB]
Get:4 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu focal/stable amd64 docker-ce-cli amd64 5:20.10.7~3-0~ubuntu-focal [41.4 MB]
Get:5 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu focal/stable amd64 docker-ce amd64 5:20.10.7~3-0~ubuntu-focal [24.8 MB]
Get:6 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu focal/stable amd64 docker-ce-rootless-extras amd64 5:20.10.7~3-0~ubuntu-focal [9063 kB]
Get:7 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu focal/stable amd64 docker-scan-plugin amd64 0.8.0~ubuntu-focal [3889 kB]
Fetched 108 MB in 5s (21.1 MB/s)
Selecting previously unselected package pigz.
(Reading database ... 46926 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../0-pigz_2.4-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking pigz (2.4-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package containerd.io.
Preparing to unpack .../1-containerd.io_1.4.6-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking containerd.io (1.4.6-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package docker-ce-cli.
Preparing to unpack .../2-docker-ce-cli_5%3a20.10.7~3-0~ubuntu-focal_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking docker-ce-cli (5:20.10.7~3-0~ubuntu-focal) ...
Selecting previously unselected package docker-ce.
Preparing to unpack .../3-docker-ce_5%3a20.10.7~3-0~ubuntu-focal_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking docker-ce (5:20.10.7~3-0~ubuntu-focal) ...
Selecting previously unselected package docker-ce-rootless-extras.
Preparing to unpack .../4-docker-ce-rootless-extras_5%3a20.10.7~3-0~ubuntu-focal_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking docker-ce-rootless-extras (5:20.10.7~3-0~ubuntu-focal) ...
Selecting previously unselected package docker-scan-plugin.
Preparing to unpack .../5-docker-scan-plugin_0.8.0~ubuntu-focal_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking docker-scan-plugin (0.8.0~ubuntu-focal) ...
Selecting previously unselected package slirp4netns.
Preparing to unpack .../6-slirp4netns_0.4.3-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking slirp4netns (0.4.3-1) ...
Setting up slirp4netns (0.4.3-1) ...
Setting up docker-scan-plugin (0.8.0~ubuntu-focal) ...
Setting up containerd.io (1.4.6-1) ...
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/containerd.service → /lib/systemd/system/containerd.service.
Setting up docker-ce-cli (5:20.10.7~3-0~ubuntu-focal) ...
Setting up pigz (2.4-1) ...
Setting up docker-ce-rootless-extras (5:20.10.7~3-0~ubuntu-focal) ...
Setting up docker-ce (5:20.10.7~3-0~ubuntu-focal) ...
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/docker.service → /lib/systemd/system/docker.service.
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/sockets.target.wants/docker.socket → /lib/systemd/system/docker.socket.
invoke-rc.d: could not determine current runlevel
Processing triggers for man-db (2.9.1-1) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (245.4-4ubuntu3.4) ...
```

But when I do `sudo systemctl status docker` I get the following:

```
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
```

When I do `sudo bash -c 'dockerd &'` I get this:

```
WARN[2021-06-03T09:05:41.638011400-05:00] grpc: addrConn.createTransport failed to connect to {unix:///var/run/docker/containerd/containerd.sock  <nil> 0 <nil>}. Err :connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial unix:///var/run/docker/containerd/containerd.sock: timeout". Reconnecting...  module=grpc
failed to start daemon: Error initializing network controller: error obtaining controller instance: failed to create NAT chain DOCKER: iptables failed: iptables -t nat -N DOCKER: iptables v1.8.4 (legacy): can't initialize iptables table `nat': Table does not exist (do you need to insmod?)
Perhaps iptables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.
 (exit status 3)
```

Here's the output of `uname -a; systemd-detect-virt; cat /etc/os-release;`:

```
Linux XPS 4.4.0-19041-Microsoft #488-Microsoft Mon Sep 01 13:43:00 PST 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
wsl
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="20.04.2 LTS (Focal Fossa)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS"
VERSION_ID="20.04"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=focal
UBUNTU_CODENAME=focal
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What are specifics of your machine? Is it a virtual machine in cloud? Do you have full root access to this machine? Which VM  hypervisor do you use? Please add the outputs of `uname -a; systemd-detect-virt; cat /etc/os-release; `  to the question by editing it.

Comment: It seems that WSL2 lacks some needed kernel or systemd modules. You have to try installation of Ubuntu in the VM instead.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add your user to the `docker` group by

```
sudo usermod -a -G docker $USER
```

and then reboot.

Note: the official Docker documentation for Ubuntu is located at https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/ .

Comment: I did `sudo usermod -a -G docker $USER` but `shutdown -r` doesn't work. I get this error: `System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate. Failed to connect to bus: Host is down`. I'm running this on WSL2 fwiw...

Comment: same issue here...